# Netty NIO Client Behaviour and Server OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: netty

This should probably be obvious to me but I'd still like to confirm the following...

Given a specific Channel and an NIO Netty server which uses the OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor and the following forms of clients:

1. *OIO blocking client* - I expect the response order to match the request order.
2. *NIO client that uses blocking reads* - I expect the response order to match the request order.
3. *Pure NIO  async client (no blocking reads)* - I will NOT expect the response order to match the request order.

Firstly, please let me know if the above is incorrect. If so, please correct me.

For assertion 3) the server still processes the requests in the order in which each event is received, but since the client is asynchronous the order in which the requests are sent is not something you can predict. True?

So, it only appears that the response order is different from the client's perspective. Due to the asynchronous nature of the client the order the requests are sent to the server isn't really known.

I need to nail down my understanding of this for a project I'm working on so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I ended up reading the OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor documentation and I now realize its quite clear that the events are processed sequentially. I also wrote a test to convince myself and there's no doubt left in my mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use TCP the response order MUST be in the order as you send them in the Server. This is only not true when using UDP.

Comment: Hi Norman and thanks. Sorry, my knowledge of TCP isn't as good as it should be. Are you saying "MUST" because the TCP protocol demands that the responses must be in corresponding order to the requests?

Comment: There is not relation between request and response.. I just say that if you write some packets on one side they will get received in the same order on the other side if you use tcp.

Comment: Indeed that covers the request side. But my question  focuses on the response order in relation to the request order. Can you verify if the three assertions I've made above are correct? Thanks again.